# How to match and rolate images? OpenCV c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, fingerprint

Long story short :

How to relate these two images? I was thinking of translating and rotating the detected image till it matches a certain percentage of the database image. Any way that I can do this? Or is there a better method?

Database image :_________________________________________________Detected image :

[image]
[image]

## **DETAILED EXPLANATION**

I'm doing a fingerprint verification system. I'm able to obtain the minutiae (bifurcation =green ; termination=red). Due to the change of image everytime, template matching algorithm isn't effective at all. The detected fingerprint changes in orientation and detected area. This is what I've done so far.

These are the template image in the database.

Original Database image :____________________________________Original Detected image :

[image]
[image]

Processed Database image :__________________________________Processed Detected image :
[image]
[image]

The processed images have gone through blurring, thresholding Otsu + adaptivethreshold to get ROI and thinning.

Comment: Take a look at the end of this article: http://answers.opencv.org/question/6364/fingerprint-matching-in-mobile-devices-android/#6370

Comment: @DavidNilosek thanks for the article. May I know how can we generate the Field Orientation Map?